# Univariate Linear Regression outputting NaN

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm currently writing an implementation of univariate linear regression on python:

```
# implementation of univariate linear regression
import numpy as np


def cost_function(hypothesis, y, m):
  return (1 / (2 * m)) * ((hypothesis - y) ** 2).sum()


def hypothesis(X, theta):
  return X.dot(theta)


def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, m, alpha):
  for i in range(1500):
    temp1 = theta[0][0] - alpha * (1 / m) * (hypothesis(X, theta) - y).sum()
    temp2 = theta[1][0] - alpha * (1 / m) * ((hypothesis(X, theta) - y) * X[:, 1]).sum()
    theta[0][0] = temp1
    theta[1][0] = temp2

  return theta

if __name__ == '__main__':
  data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',')

  y = data[:, 1]
  m = y.size
  X = np.ones(shape=(m, 2))
  X[:, 1] = data[:, 0]
  theta = np.zeros(shape=(2, 1))
  alpha = 0.01

  print(gradient_descent(X, y, theta, m, alpha))
```

This code will output NaN for theta, after going to infinity - I can't figure out what's going wrong, but it's surely something to do with my changing of theta in the gradient descent function.

The data I'm using is a simple linear regression pairs dataset I got online - and that loads in correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that when you do `X[:,1]` or `data[:,1]`, you get objects of shape (m,). When you multiply an object of shape (m,) with a matrix of shape (m,1), you get a matrix of size (m,m)

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[4],[5],[6]])
(a*b).shape #prints (3,3)
```

If you do
    y=y.reshape((m,1))
in your `if __name__` block and inside your gradient_descent function you do

```
X_1 = X[:,1].reshape((m,1))
```

Should fix the problem. Right now what's happening is that when you do

```
((hypothesis(X, theta) - y) * X[:, 1])
```

you're getting a 100 by 100 matrix, which is not what you want.

Full code I used for testing is:

```
# implementation of univariate linear regression
import numpy as np


def cost_function(hypothesis, y, m):
  return (1 / (2 * m)) * ((hypothesis - y) ** 2).sum()


def hypothesis(X, theta):
  return X.dot(theta)


def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, m, alpha):
  X_1 = X[:,1]
  X_1 = X_1.reshape((m,1))
  for i in range(1500):
    temp1 = theta[0][0] - alpha * (1 / m) * (hypothesis(X, theta) - y).sum()
    temp2 = theta[1][0] - alpha * (1 / m) * ((hypothesis(X, theta) - y) * X_1).sum()
    theta[0][0] = temp1
    theta[1][0] = temp2

  return theta

if __name__ == '__main__':
  data= np.random.normal(size=(100,2))

  y = 30*data[:,0] + data[:, 1]
  m = y.size
  X = np.ones(shape=(m, 2))
  y = y.reshape((m,1))
  X[:, 1] = data[:, 0]
  theta = np.zeros(shape=(2, 1))
  alpha = 0.01

  print(gradient_descent(X, y, theta, m, alpha))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to fix the problem - same output as before.

Comment: Still no luck! The same output as before. I've inserted y = y.reshape((m, 1)) directly after the declaration of m in the if __name__ block, and x1 = X[:, 1].reshape((m, 1)) at the top of gradient_descent.

Comment: what data did you use?

Comment: generated my own at random so I'd know the true slope and intercept

Comment: http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/brase/understandable_statistics/7e/students/datasets/slr/frames/frame.html I'm using the list price vs best price dataset here to no avail. I get RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars on the line where I'm assigning to temp2, probably due to the NaN

Comment: I uploaded my full code. It correctly outputs intercept of ~0 and slope ~30

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150233/discussion-between-ryan-stout-and-bag).